# setContentView can't be resolved in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I know it is a known issue, but my `ide`(android studio) is saying that `setContentView` can't be resolved. In fact, it was working perfect well but I tried to import some android plugin but then I deleted all the plugin files I added. Then I noticed that `setContentView` wasn't recognized anymore.

I tried everything I found on `SO` (cleaning, rebuilding....). I read it is mainly related to the `xml` `view` files, but I have no error in these files. How can I do ?

Update :

when running gradle build, I get some success build. Then when I want to run the project, I get in my console

```
org.gradle.execution.TaskSelectionException: Task 'compileDebug' is ambiguous in root project 'NewsFeeder'. Candidates are: 'compileDebugAidl', 'compileDebugJava', 'compileDebugNdk', 'compileDebugRenderscript', 'compileDebugTestAidl', 'compileDebugTestJava', 'compileDebugTestNdk', 'compileDebugTestRenderscript
```

Edit 2 : here's my layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="400px"
    android:layout_height="800px">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
        />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="false"

        />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Edit 3: I restart the `ide`, and now I get in the `activity_main` file

```
Failed to find style 'listViewStyle' in current theme (8 similar errors not shown) "?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" in attribute "minHeight" is not a valid format. (Edit) (3 similar errors not shown)
```

Comment: Check that your activity extends `android.app.Activity` either directly or indirectly and the relevant imports are in place.

Comment: What version of Android Studio?

Comment: @ScottBarta I am using 0.4.3 version

Comment: Can you post your code? import statements and onCreate method?

Comment: You've tried the Sync Project with Gradle Files button?

Comment: @ScottBarta yes i tried it

Comment: @ScottBarta in fact when running gradle build, I get some `success build`. Then when I want to run the project, I get :`org.gradle.execution.TaskSelectionException: Task 'compileDebug' is ambiguous in root project 'NewsFeeder'. Candidates are: 'compileDebugAidl', 'compileDebugJava', 'compileDebugNdk', 'compileDebugRenderscript', 'compileDebugTestAidl', 'compileDebugTestJava', 'compileDebugTestNdk', 'compileDebugTestRenderscript`

Comment: Please update your question. It's very confusing to try to read detailed info in comments.

Comment: please post your layout

Comment: @ScottBarta I have just updated my post

Comment: @Amrola I have just updated my post !

Comment: @Amrola Check my answer and confirm. I don't feel good to write long String in comments so posted it as answer.

Comment: @ScottBarta I have just updated my post, something seems to be wrong in my layout file, but I don't know what...

Comment: are you using any style ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
Make sure that setContentView is in the onCreate Method, and that all the other required pieces of code are in the method. Here is a basic template to help you out

```
package com.example.app
import android.app.Activity;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you have deleted all plugins make sure some required plugins are still there in place.

You can check them from `Settings > Plugins`

[image]

It seems android plugins default tasks are missing so make sure you have

```
apply plugin: 'android'
```

in your module's build.gradle file.

**EDIT(As per the discussion in comments) :**

It seems you are using actionbarsherlock in your project make sure you have applied Sherlock theme in your AndroidManifest.xml file

Something Like this :

If you are using style.xml for you theming

In your **style.xml**

```
 <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
 </style>

  <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

  //other style elements here or leave it blank

  </style>
```

in your **AndroidManifest.xml** file

```
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

   </application>
```

Comment: All the settings are ok, but  I have just updated my post, something seems to be wrong in my layout file, but I don't know what...

Comment: The layout xml file you have posted is of activity_main.xml or fragment_main.xml because the attributes in error are not there in xml ?

Comment: I posted `activity_main.xml`, which is required by `MainActivity` which inherits from `FragmentActivity`...

Comment: but `android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"` no where in the xml please check whether your xml is correct or not .

Comment: I know, it is very weird, when I run some grep command, I find `listPreferredItemHeight` in the build files. Should I delete this directory ?

Comment: It can be there in your list_view_items layout xml file.

Comment: but I don't have any list_view_items file. Should I delete the `build` directory ?

Comment: You can try `Build > Clean Project` for this.

Comment: but then how are your inflating items in list view declared above , which layout are you using in your adapter's getView method ?

Comment: Still getting the same errors, but when I grep in my whole project, I get 2 matching files containing `listPreferredItemHeight` : `Binary file classes/production/actionbarsherlock/com/actionbarsherlock/R$attr.class matches
Binary file classes/production/actionbarsherlock/com/actionbarsherlock/R$styleable.class matches`. How can it be ?

Comment: I get the same problem. In fact, in my manifest, I have : `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` where in `style.xml`, I have `<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    </style>`

Comment: ya this is the issue change `android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` to `Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar` in your style.xml as parent theme.

Comment: Should I delete manually the `build` and `classes` directories

Comment: Ok now `Theme` in `Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar` is not recognized, but `android:Theme` is recognized

Comment: There were some issue in Android Studio 0.4.2 , do upgrade to 0.4.3 . If you already running on 0.4.3 please update your queatiin and include your project structure, build.gradle and settings.gradle files

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46804/discussion-between-pyus13-and-user1611830)